# How to handle Slick db object in akka

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I've got a program that schedules a task once a day.
Each day, it gets data from an outside API and stores the results into my database. I've chosen to do this with akka actors, using Slick for connecting to my database.

The way the "database inserting" side of the app works as follow:

- requests for inserting data are addressed to a "DatabaseInsertManager" actor
- for each incoming request, this Manager creates a child "DatabaseInserter" that will actually make the call to the database, given the request provided by the manager
- when the request is done, the inserter dies

In order to call the database, I have a global reference to a database Slick object, that these DatabaseInserters all use. I'm wondering if that's the correct way of doing it. Can this global reference die for some reason?
Or, is it better to create a new DB object for each DatabaseInverter, that uses `db.close()` at the `postStop` method?
Last option is: I create a db object at the start of the daily job, and close it when the job is done (usually 15 minutes later).

My slick dependencies are

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.3",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.3",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [thread pool & connection pool](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.1/database.html#database-thread-pool) capabilities of slick when configuring your `Database` then you should be able to share a "global reference" without negative consequences from a long running application.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I believe that this is what I've put in place and indeed it seems to work well on the long run!